# is there a way in visual studio to digitally sign cpp files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, digital-signature

is there a way/extension in visual studio that i digitally sign code and header files so that the developers having access to private key can modify the code and update the digital signature and the other developers can only compile the code. i am unable to find any such while googling.

example is below:

class ABC
{
};

//1234557729997766666

Comment: What does it mean " can only compile the code". Since it's text files, anyone can change them.

Comment: You can sign git commits.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis we want a check and balance for the privileged dev with private key who can make changes to code and update the digital signature vs non-privileged who can only compile the code that has the digital signature in its cpp and h files. digital signature can be in commented form in the end of the  file.

Comment: You could give non-privileged devs access to a read-only filesystem containing the source, but that wouldn't prevent them from copying the code, changing it, and compiling their own copies.

Comment: i was impressed by MAGIC programming language on which meditech healthcare system is build upon. it has digital signature in the end of each code file. you can see the code but can not modify and run with its cli as you dont have the private key. thanks everyone for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Git(Version control system). It will help to keep track of changes in your code. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) is the tutorial for Git on visual studio. Information about the Git user access can be found [here](https://wincent.com/wiki/Git_repository_access_control).